# Firebase Deployment Error: JavaScript Cloud Functions onWorkFormCreated and onTalentFormCreated Fail Container Healthcheck on Cloud Run

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a cloud function on Firebase but it gives me following error:

Error:

```
Could not create or update Cloud Run service onworkformcreated, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'onworkformcreated-00001-hab' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.
```

I have am trying to deploy with custom
Code:

```
/* eslint-disable */

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { onValueCreated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// Initialize Firebase
const serviceAccount = require("../firebase-adminsdk.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "Firebase Realtime Database URL",
});

// Initialize SendGrid
const sendgridApiKey = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridApiKey);

// Sender email
const senderEmail = "some@gmail.com";

// Function to send confirmation email
async function sendConfirmationEmail(userType, userEmail, firstName, lastName) {
  // Email Content goes here
}

// Realtime Database trigger for 'work' node
exports.onWorkFormCreated = onValueCreated("/work/{pushId}", (event) => {
  const formData = event.data.val();
  sendConfirmationEmail(
    formData.userType,
    formData.email,
    formData.firstName,
    formData.lastName,
  );
});


// Realtime Database trigger for 'talent' node
exports.onTalentFormCreated = onValueCreated("/talent/{pushId}", (event) => {
    const formData = event.data.val();
    sendConfirmationEmail(
      formData.userType,
      formData.email,
      formData.firstName,
      formData.lastName,
    );
});
```

I try deploying with different versions of Node.Js like version 16, 18, and 20 nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote the code in firebase gen 1 instead of gen 2 and it worked.

Firebase documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?gen=1st